# React pdf + Create React apps issue, jay peg module throwing error

Tags: react-pdf

I am currently using the versions "react-pdf": "4.1.0" and "react": "^16.1.1". Previously, my implementation with react-pdf was functioning correctly. However, yesterday, I deleted the node_modules directory and executed npm install. Since then, my code has encountered an error, and I am seeking assistance to resolve this issue. Any guidance or support would be greatly appreciated.

[image]